# Unable to access a class from the same package

Tags: java, class, package

I have 2 classes in java

```
//file: A.java
package files;

public class A {
   B b;
}
```

the next file

```
//file: B.java
package files;

public class B {}
```

Now when I compile A.java using

```
javac A.java
```

I get the error

```
unable to resolve symbol B
```

Although, if I don't mention the package line, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
cd [root] (the upper directory of files)

javac -classpath "." files/A.java
```

Have a look here for the basic principles: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile all classes of your project

try this

```
javac A.java B.java
```

or

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: This will fail too, because no classpath was set